# How to move a panel to one of many locations

Tags: c#, location, panel, sender

I'm trying to make a panel move to the same location as a label I click but I can't figure it out.

I have gotten it to work with specific code like 
"Stats1.Location = wood.Location;" but I would need to do that up to 10 Times so I've been trying to make something more dynamic with sender.

```
private void Wood_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Stats();
        }

void Stats() 
        {
            var X = sender;
            Panel1.Location = X.Location;
        }
```

I was hoping this would work somewhat like Visual Basic and it would use "sender.Location" in place of "wood.Location" but it just says "the name 'sender' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: `Panel1.Location = (sender as Control).Location;` ?

Comment: You call `Stats` where `sender` is unknown. Instead make `sender` a parameter of `Stats` and call it like @vasily.sib suggested

Comment: @user1781290 how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of duplicating the code for each label handler (making it call Stats), simply select each Label and make its Click event point to a common handler like the one below:

```
private void All_Labels_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Label lbl = (Label)sender;
        Panel1.Location = lbl.Location;
}
```

To be clear, in the properties pane, click the lightning bolt icon, find the Click entry, then change the dropdown on the right to All_Labels_Click.

Comment: Why does "Label lbl" have the lbl?

Comment: This works like a charm and answered some other questions I had, thanks so much.